# pair of random colors in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following code
How I "paint" each 2 cards in the same color (I do a memory game)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    function generateRandomColor() {
        var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        return randomColor;

    }
    var grid = document.querySelector(".grid");


    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        grid.innerHTML += '<div  class="card" ></div>';
        var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
        cards[i].style.backgroundColor = generateRandomColor();
        
    }    
})
```

have no idea how to do pairs

Comment: You could increase the step in your for loop, e.g. i+=2 and then handle two elements instead of just one.

Comment: can you please write me how you would do it?

Comment: To style the newly created element, you could rather style it directly instead of selecting all cards created so far, for up to 50 times, and then ignore up to 49 not actually used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. I assumed that the colors should be distributed randomly, and not in a row every 2 cards. So the main thing here - we need to generate a pairs array to assign each color twice for random cards.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  function generateRandomColors(colorsCount) {
    const colors = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < colorsCount; i++) {
      colors.push('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
    }
    return colors;
  }

  function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
  }

  const cardsCount = 50;
  const colorsCount = Math.floor(cardsCount / 2);
  const colors = generateRandomColors(colorsCount);
  const allIndices = Array.from(Array(cardsCount).keys());

  shuffleArray(allIndices);

  const pairs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < colorsCount; i++) {
    const index1 = allIndices[i * 2];
    const index2 = allIndices[i * 2 + 1];
    pairs.push([index1, index2]);
  }

  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  for (let i = 0; i < cardsCount; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.className = "card";
    card.innerText = i
    grid.appendChild(card);
  }

  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  for (let i = 0; i < colorsCount; i++) {
    const color = colors[i];
    const pair = pairs[i];
    const index1 = pair[0];
    const index2 = pair[1];
    cards[index1].style.backgroundColor = color;
    cards[index2].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the step in your for loop. Also, to avoid redundant lookups of all cards created so far, for up to 50 times, and then ignore up to 49 not actually used, you should the newly created element directly, like this (untested code):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i+=2) {
    var randomColor = generateRandomColor();
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
         var card = document.createElement('div');
         card.classList.add('card');
         card.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
         grid.appendChild(card);
    }        
}
```

Comment: thanks! but newContent is not defined

Comment: This was just to make you think ;-) ... no it was actually a copy and paste error, this must be appendChild(card) of course. See in context here: https://codepen.io/openmindculture/pen/KKxGwXb

Comment: thanks! but it doesnt work

Comment: what exactly does not work? Maybe we're missing the class name .card, but we could add that as well: `card.classList.add('card')`